# From javascript dictionary inserting to mysql with php a null value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dictionary

Good day!

What i am trying to do is inserting a null value from a dictionary (JSON string, whatever) to mysql database. It is clear on the console that the value of my data is null but when inserting it fails. I tried hard coding the null on the php and it was successful. I wonder why it returns an error when the null value was from the dictionary.

ex 1:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (field1) VALUES (" . $data['item'] . ")" <-- not working if item == null
```

ex 2:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (field1) VALUES (null)" <-- tried testing this if the db accepts null and was successful
```

i tried finding some same question because i know this can be a common question but i failed to find the answer and quite having a hard time myself figuring out why this happens.

Thanks a lot people!

Comment: have you checked `var_dump($data['item'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More details will help a lot, but best guess is because PHP converts null to an empty string, so you are building this query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (field1) VALUES ()";
```

Which would rightly give you an SQL error.  Try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (field1) VALUES (" . ( is_null( $data['item'] ) ? 'null' : $data['item'] ) . ")";
```

Also, you are likely vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).  You should always use prepared queries.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. Now i tried creating a log and it shows that php converted it into '' (empty string). Hmm am i still vulnerable even if i filter the whole json that if it has an apostrophe it would be multiplied by two so that mysql can register the user's input?

Comment: or do you have any recommendations to prevent that? I am planning to make stored functions for everything and using mysqli. Is that good enough?

Comment: Your best bet is to ask some of your questions over on information security: https://security.stackexchange.com/  As always, make sure and provide plenty of details about so your question can be thoroughly answered.  SQL Injection is a complicated topic, a common security vulnerability, and one that hackers will actively scan for.  Definitely worth learning about.  I would say to keep it simple: strong input filtering, prepared queries, whitelist dynamic queries.  Stored functions can also be vulnerable to SQL injection, so check them carefully too.

Answer (score 0):

Now i get it. The value *NULL* is = to '' because it really contains nothing(''). But when i include apostrophe before and after the word NULL it prints on my query the word NULL. Just some minor mistakes.